# Eclipse execution slower than in another pc

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, performance

I'm developing in Eclipse in Java and I noticed that the software execution in my eclipse is much slower (like 6 or 7 times) than the same code run in eclipse in another similar pc (both have 8gb ram 8 cores). The only difference is that I'm running on windows 7 and the other pc is running ubuntu 13.04.
I already checked and I'm using the right virtual machine (jre 1.7, the linux one is with jre 1.6) and there are at most about 20 prints on the console over a 6 minute run. Also I'm running as "run" and not debug.
What can it be? Is it possible that under linux is much faster?

UPDATE:
I installed a partition with Debian 7 on the same laptop with windows (where it was running slower). With both the default open jdk 1.6 and the new java 1.8 Debian is much faster. I would say ok if it was like 2 times slower, but a 6 minute execution instead of a 1 minute one is a bit strange.

Answer (score 1):

Linux is in fact faster (usually) than Windows. It depends on alot of things though, RAM and cores are not only things that matter. CPU architecture, clock speed, OC or not and so on. If you´d post both computers specifications then it would be easier to answer but until then there's your answer.

Comment: Hi, I updated the question, now i made a Debian partition and I get 6-7 times better performance on linux than on windows in the SAME laptop. I would understand something like 2-3 better but I think there's still a problem.

Comment: No problem, it is a usual occurence, basically every OS is better optimised than Windows, get used to it, it is pretty good. :)

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is use a Terminal on each platform:

First do a [java -version](http://www.wikihow.com/Determine-Java-Version) to make sure both are really using the Oracle JVM (for example, on Ubuntu, a trivial installation of Oracle JDK may not guaranee that you're not still using the original Open JDK).

Then, run your Java program in the terminal on each machine, and see  if the difference persists. If it doesn't (i.e. if you only have the big performance gap when running from Eclipse), then it might be Eclipse's fault. While Java does tend to be faster on Linux/Debian vs. Windows, Eclipse might not have the same trend. If your experiment shows that Eclipse is the reason for the performance gap:

- make sure that Eclipse is configured to use the Oracle JVM on each platform
- make sure Eclipse itself and all it's possible plugins are updated (and if not, update first Eclipse, then its plugins).

Comment: Hi, I've updated java on windows and this is now what I have, still slow, both in eclipse and terminal.

java version "1.8.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.11-b03, mixed mode)

Now I installed a partition with Debian 7 on the same laptop with windows. With both the default open jdk 1.6 and the new java 1.8 is faster. I guess then that on windows is 6 times slower